# UISwipeGestureRecognizer selector not called. Any idea why?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm using the code below to integrate right/left swipe events to a UIImageView object (called **photo_view**) but it did not work after tests in iphone simulator and device. The methods **handleLeftSwipe** and **handleRightSwipe** below are not even called as logging didn't print anything in the debugger logs as it should. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
     leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
     leftSwipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
     [photo_view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];
     leftSwipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
     [leftSwipeRecognizer release];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
     rightSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
     rightSwipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
     [photo_view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeRecognizer];
     rightSwipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
     [rightSwipeRecognizer release];

}


- (void)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
     NSLog(@"handleLeftSwipe called");
}

- (void)handleRightSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
     NSLog(@"handleRightSwipe called");
}
```

Any idea what the reason ?

Thx in advance for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIImageView` instances defaults `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`. Try setting it to `YES`.

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure you're also including the `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in your .h file.